# Transparent redirect or proxy in Apache, preserving incoming request

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy, transparent-proxy

When a user first hits our server, we want to capture some information about the incoming request: `GET` parameters, `Referer` header, &c. The general idea is that when we get an incoming request that matches some `RewriteCond`s (doesn't have a cookie, doesn't have a particular `GET` param in case they don't accept cookies, &c.), we use a `RewriteRule` with `[P]` to transparently proxy the request to a servlet (actually a Spring controller, if that matters) that will analyse the incoming request, then send a 302, with a new cookie set, to redirect the user to the originally requested URL. That is,

- User requests `/foo.html`
- `mod_rewrite` detects that this is the user's first request (no cookie, no `GET` flag param)
- A `RewriteRule` with `[P]` proxies to `/my/spring/controller`
- Servlet analyses the request and responds with a 302 to `Location: /foo.html`.

The first three steps are simple enough. The problem is that in step four, the servlet has no idea that `/foo.html` was ever requested, which means (a) it can't record the fact that such was the case (a business requirement) and (b) it doesn't know where to redirect. We can see which *server* was requested in `X-Forwarded-Host` *et al*, but looking at the request URL just shows `/my/spring/controller`.

What we want to achieve, then, is ideally a proxy pass transparent not just to the client but to the receiving servlet as well.

One option is to pass the URL in an environment variable with something like `[E=FOO:REQUEST_URI]`. However, this increases the complexity of the servlet, and it's not obvious to me whether the request is otherwise unchanged. The point of the servlet is to analyse the request coming from the client, preferably unchanged by Apache. If `mod_rewrite` changed the request URL, can I trust all other aspects of the request to be unchanged?

Answer (score 0):

Trust mod_rewrite, and if paranoid pass the stuff your interested in to your applet, as a series of CGI variables e.g.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}  !.........
RewriteRule /?foo.html   /my/spring/controller?theRequest=%{THE_REQUEST}&requestURI=%{REQUEST_URI}&referer=%{HTTP_REFERER} [P,L]
```